# send() socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

While trying to implement a server and client, I noticed that the client was writing to stdout instead 
of through the network. I figured out that the file descriptor being returned by connect() is always zero, which explains why it was writing to stdout. But I can not figure out why connect() always returns zero instead of a valid socket. All the articles on the web I found with the same problem were due to precedence issues with wrapping if() around the connect() call. But I haven't done that, any help would be appreciated.

server code

```
 int setUpServer(struct fuzzerObj *ptr, int *firstClient)
 {
     /* Declarations */
    int hostSocket, yes = 1, rtrn, clientfd;

    union
    {
        struct sockaddr_in in;

    }address;

    /* Create Socket */
    hostSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hostSocket < 0)
    {
        errorHandler("Could not create socket\n", FUNCTION_ID_SET_UP_SERVER);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Reuse Address */
    rtrn = setsockopt(hostSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        errorHandler("Couldn't Reuse Address\n", FUNCTION_ID_SET_UP_SERVER);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set Up Struct */
    address.in.sin_len = sizeof(address.in);
    address.in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.in.sin_port = htons(BBPORT_NUMBER);
    address.in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    memset(address.in.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(address.in.sin_zero));

    /* Bind Address to Socket */
    rtrn = bind(hostSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &address, address.in.sin_len);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        errorHandler("Can't Bind Address to Socket\n", FUNCTION_ID_SET_UP_SERVER);
        return -1;
    }

    /* listen */
    rtrn = listen(hostSocket, ptr->numberOfClients);
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        errorHandler("Can't Listen\n", FUNCTION_ID_SET_UP_SERVER);
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        rtrn = acceptClient(hostSocket, &clientfd);
        if(rtrn < 0)
        {
            printf("Can't Accept Client\n");
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    }
    *firstClient = clientfd;
    return 0;
 }
```

client code

```
 #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 #define BLACKBOX_PORT 9696

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     /* Check To See If an argument was passed */
     if(argc < 2)
     {
         printf("No enough Arguments\n");
         return -1;
      }

     /* Declaration's */
    const char *ip = argv[1];
    int sockfd, fd, rtrn;
    char *outBuf;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    /* Get Socket to Connect to Fuzz Server */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't Create Socket");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Fill Out Struct */
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(BLACKBOX_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &servaddr.sin_addr);

    /* Attempt Connection */
    fd = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Can not connect to BlackBox Fuzz server");
        return -1;
     }

     /* Allocate Space in Memory for Outgoing Connection */
     rtrn = asprintf(&outBuf, "Mac OSX 10.9\n");
     if(rtrn < 0)
     {
         perror("Copy Error");
         return -1;
     }

     /* Send Data to Fuzzer via Socket */
     rtrn = send(fd, outBuf, strlen(outBuf), 0);
     if(rtrn < 0)
     {
          perror("Can't write Data to BlackBox Server");
          return -1;
     }
     free(outBuf);

     return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon successfully calling `connect()`, the `sockfd` is connected. The `0` return value indicates that the call is successful. If the value was not `0`, it would have indicated an error, and that the connection attempt has failed or is not yet completed (if the connect is non-blocking).

After determining that `connect()` has succeeded, call `send()` on the `sockfd`, not on the return value of the `connect()` call.

```
     rtrn = send(sockfd, outBuf, strlen(outBuf), 0);
```

Comment: cool, i guess i was thinking connect() was like accept(), should have read the man pages.

Comment: `accept()` uses an unconnected bound socket to represent the listener. Using a socket this way has the side-effect of giving you a pollable handle to use to asynchronously determine if a client is trying to connect. `accept()` then returns a new socket to represent the newly established connection, leaving the listener socket alone so that it can continue to serve its purpose.